# how to force data go through NICs rather than lookback

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, ping

guys

I have a board with two PCIe network card, I connected the two ports with a network wire, now, I need to transfer packets from one port to the other one. For example, I configured PORT1 with IP: 100.1.1.1, PORT2: 100.1.1.2, then ping 100.1.1.2, it seems fine, but actually, it is bypassed by internal lookback, traffic doesn't go like PORT1 --> PORT2.

My question is how to force packet go from PORT1 to PORT2?

Comment: any solution? i've the same problem